# Bootstrap dropdown menu hidden behind other rows

Tags: css

i have GroupBy:Threat name and potential impect drop-down button  but

when data get loaded from server in a div having id "listThreat",drop-down menu not get displayed.

when data not get displayed dropdown works fine but when i click on any Dropdown menu option element it shows effect on all button in the page like potential impect button name get changed to element.
below is my code

```
    <div class="panel" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100vh"
                    id="ThreatList">
                    <header class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!--first row of  column -->
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div>Threat List</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div>Total Threat:</div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
</header>



                    <div class="row">
                        <!--second row of column -->
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle"
                                    type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Group By:threat
                                    Name</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Threat Name</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs  dropdown-toggle"
                                    type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Sort By:Potential
                                    Impect</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Potential Impect</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mitigation</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Validation</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div id="listThreat"></div>
                            <!-- end of second row -->
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can u give me working demo link or image?

Comment: Get us a demo link like on jsfiddle or jsbin.